# Defining a norm on Vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces

> Let V be a $\mathbb{R}$-Vector space with inner product $\langle •,• \rangle  : V\times V \to \mathbb{R}$ 
>   Notice $||v||=\sqrt{\langle v,v \rangle}$
>   Define a norm on V$$

What are they specifically asking me to do? Do they want me to show that $||v||=\sqrt{\langle v,v \rangle}$ is a norm by showing it satisfies homogeneity, non-negativity, Triangle inequality and that $\|v\|=0$ if and if only $v=0$, or do they want me to do show something else?

Comment: It doesn't look like they're asking you to do anything here.  Is there some sort of continuation to the question?

Comment: Yes this is one part of 3, but aren't they asking me to do something by asking me to define the norm?

Comment: I suspect that they meant to write "notice $\|v\| = \sqrt{\langle v,v \rangle}$ **defines** a norm on $V$"

Comment: I think you're right about that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to check that that function $\|\cdot\|\colon V\to \mathbb{R}$ given by 
$$
\|v\|=\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}
$$

satisfies the axioms of the norm that you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, can I use Cauchy–Schwarz for proving this follows triangle inequality?

Comment: In order to prove the triangle inequality holds, yes.